# XSLT apply-templates recursively does not work

Tags: xml, xslt

I plan to apply a template recursively to scan through all the items (rows and columns) in the input XML.

Here is the input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">

     <item row="1" column="1" colspan="3">
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="3">
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
     </item>
  </layout>
</ui>
```

Here is my code:

```
<!-- **********************  Main Program ********************** -->
    <xsl:variable name="maxR" select="xs:integer(max(layout/item/@row))" as="xs:integer" />
    <xsl:variable name="maxC" select="xs:integer(max(layout/item/@column))" as="xs:integer" />

    (<xsl:value-of select="$maxR"/>, <xsl:value-of select="$maxC"/>)

    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="layout/item">
        <xsl:with-param name="curR" select="0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="curC" select="0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="maxR" select="$maxR"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="maxC" select="$maxC"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>

<!-- **********************   Template   ********************** -->

  <xsl:template name="grpBxRC" match="layout/item">
    <xsl:param name="curR" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="curC" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxR" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxC" as="xs:integer"/>

    [<xsl:value-of select="$curR"/>, <xsl:value-of select="$curC"/>]

    <xsl:if test="$maxC > $curC">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="layout/item">
        <xsl:with-param name="curR" select="$curR"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="curC" select="$curC + 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="maxR" select="$maxR"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="maxC" select="$maxC"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

When I run it, I got output as:

```
(1, 3)
[0, 0] [0, 0] [0, 0] [0, 0] [0, 0] [0, 0] [0, 0] [0, 0]
```

(1,3) is correct for maxR and maxC. However, I expect

```
(1,3)
[0,0] [0,1] [0,2]
```

I don't what's wrong? It seems $curC + 1 did not work?

Comment: To allow us to easily understand and reproduce the problem, please provide a minimal but complete XML input as well.

Comment: You have no nested `layout/item` elements so where do you expect any recursion to happen if the `apply-templates` uses that path. You have a flat structure you process with the first apply-templates.

Comment: It would help to know the semantics of what you are trying to achieve. Your code is clearly wrong, but it's hard to correct it without knowing what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have missed some lines to copy your xslt code above. Considering the below as your current xslt code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
            version="3.0">

<xsl:variable name="maxR" select="xs:integer(max(//layout/item/@row))" as="xs:integer"/>
<xsl:variable name="maxC" select="xs:integer(max(//layout/item/@column))" as="xs:integer"/>

<xsl:template match="/ui">
    (<xsl:value-of select="$maxR"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$maxC"/>)
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="layout/item">
            <xsl:with-param name="curR" select="0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="curC" select="0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="maxR" select="$maxR"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="maxC" select="$maxC"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<!-- **********************   Template   ********************** -->
<xsl:template name="grpBxRC" match="layout/item">
    <xsl:param name="curR" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="curC" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxR" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxC" as="xs:integer"/>

    [<xsl:value-of select="$curR"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$curC"/>]

    <xsl:if test="$maxC > $curC">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="layout/item">
            <xsl:with-param name="curR" select="$curR"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="curC" select="$curC + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="maxR" select="$maxR"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="maxC" select="$maxC"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From your expected output, it looks like you're trying to print matrix elements or table cells from maximum no. of row and column you get `i.e. (1,3)`

> In your xslt, the `<xsl:apply-templates select="layout/item">` call in
> `<xsl:template name="grpBxRC" match="layout/item">` template doesn't
> work because it couldn't match the node without any reference of it's
> parent node. It can work by changing it to `/ui/layout/item` OR
> `//layout/item`, although it won't give the required output.
>
> You could also use `<xsl:call-template>` here instead of
> `<xsl:apply-templates>` as below, BUT that will call the whole
> template `<xsl:template name="grpBxRC" match="layout/item">` as many
> times as node `<item>` appears in `<layout>` due to use of apply-templates

```
<!-- **********************   Template   ********************** -->
<xsl:template name="grpBxRC" match="layout/item">
<xsl:param name="curR" as="xs:integer"/>
<xsl:param name="curC" as="xs:integer"/>
<xsl:param name="maxR" as="xs:integer"/>
<xsl:param name="maxC" as="xs:integer"/>

<xsl:if test="$maxC > $curC">

[<xsl:value-of select="$curR"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$curC"/>]

<xsl:call-template name="grpBxRC">
    <xsl:with-param name="curR" select="$curR"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="curC" select="$curC + 1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="maxR" select="$maxR"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="maxC" select="$maxC"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

In order to achieve your expected result, one way could be as below if you have specific requirements to stick to having dynamic columns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
            version="3.0">

<xsl:variable name="maxR" select="xs:integer(max(//layout/item/@row))" as="xs:integer"/>
<xsl:variable name="maxC" select="xs:integer(max(//layout/item/@column))" as="xs:integer"/>

<xsl:template match="/ui">

    (<xsl:value-of select="$maxR"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$maxC"/>)
    
    <xsl:call-template name="grpBxRC">
        <xsl:with-param name="node" select="layout/item"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="curR" select="0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="curC" select="0"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="maxR" select="$maxR"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="maxC" select="$maxC"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="grpBxRC">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:param name="curR" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="curC" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxR" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxC" as="xs:integer"/>

    <xsl:if test="$maxC > $curC">
        [<xsl:value-of select="$curR"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$curC"/>]
        <xsl:call-template name="grpBxRC">
            <xsl:with-param name="node"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="curR" select="$curR"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="curC" select="$curC + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="maxR" select="$maxR"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="maxC" select="$maxC"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, if you want both row and column to be increased dynamically, you could go with following solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
            version="3.0">

<xsl:variable name="maxR" select="xs:integer(max(//layout/item/@row))" as="xs:integer"/>
<xsl:variable name="maxC" select="xs:integer(max(//layout/item/@column))" as="xs:integer"/>

<xsl:template match="/ui">
    (<xsl:value-of select="$maxR"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$maxC"/>)
    <xsl:call-template name="iterate-row">
        <xsl:with-param name="row" select="0"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="iterate-row">
    <xsl:param name="row"/>

    <xsl:if test="$maxR > $row">
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate-column">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col" select="0"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

        <xsl:call-template name="iterate-row">
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="iterate-column">
    <xsl:param name="col"/>
    <xsl:param name="row"/>

    <xsl:if test="$maxC > $col ">
        [<xsl:value-of select="$row"/>,<xsl:value-of select="$col"/>]
        <xsl:call-template name="iterate-column">
            <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```